# Jupyter does not work without kernel restart after exception

Tags: jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, ipython, jupyter, exceptions

I need to kill and restart the kernel of Jupyter upon encountering an exception in the code. Otherwise, none of the cells will execute. This happens with **any** script, i.e. it can be something as simple as `print('Hello, world!)` (missing the closing apostrophe). Killing and restarting the kernel is extremely annoying, as I'm losing all my variables etc. from previous calculations, so I need to rerun the entire script cell by cell. Why is this happening and can this behavior be changed somehow? Is this a "feature" of Jupyter/IPython or a bug? Also, I often have to "force" a cell to execute by pressing Shift+Enter twice, because after the first time the cell would just stay busy indefinitely (showing `[*]`).

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine and installed `pip` using [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), then Jupyter via `pip install`, then all the Python packages I need for my work. I never had this problem on any other machine, either running Windows or various Linux distros.

Comment: Please limit your post to a single issue or question. Also, please show any error logs you can find that are relevant to the situation.

Comment: The post is limited to a single issue, please read title and text body carefully. The "forced" execution of cells is not intended to be a separate issue but is given as an observation in conjunction with the kernel restart issue. Both concern failure to execute code, although the underlying causal relationship between both "symptoms" remains unclear until the problem is solved and the root cause explained fully. Can you contribute an idea or a suggestion how I could tackle this issue?

Comment: I just checked on my Ubuntu vanilla jupyter-lab: none of this can be reproduced. It keeps working as expected even after exceptions and errors. Restarts are not required. So you problem is not a generic jupyter problem. This is jupyter notebook 6.0.3. and python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem: After any exception in the code, the cells are not executing any more. Restarting the Kernel helps but is annoying.

I also experience the problem with having to execute cells twice to get the results.

We have this problem on different Win10 machines using recent versions of winpython. It started a few month ago and apparently affects different builds.

Comment: This is not really an answer but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue devoted to this bug, when it will be closed, this post may be considered as an answer:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6526

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1152982)